# Half distance / double distance algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithms

I load data from a website's pages. The problem is that the ammount of pages is unkown.

Since this process takes a long time, I want to display a progress dialog. For that I have to find the last page. My idea to find the last page is:

- Try to load page 1000

  - if page 1000 exists try to load page 2000

    - if page 2000 exists try to load page 4000
    - if page 2000 does not exist try to load page 1500
  - if page 1000 does not exist try to load page 500

    - if page 500 exists try to load page 750
    - if page 500 does not exist try to load page 250

and so on..
So simply doubling/halfing the distance between the pages.

I am stuck and failing to implement this algorithm in C#.
Since searching for 'Half distance / double distance algorithm' brought up no usefull results, maybe here someone can tell me more about it.

Is there a sample implementation for this kind of problem or does this specific kind of algorithm have a name?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: While this doesn't answer your direct question, you could just query the size of the requested data set first, before the retrieval. Then you will know up front how many records you will be getting.

Comment: @EricKing this is sadly not possible if I understood you correctly. I know that every page has 250 records (except the last one), but I don't konw how many pages there are.

Comment: So you just request the page and it is there or not?   If a page is 250 I would start there.  Two bubs and you are at 1000.

Comment: "I am stuck and failing to implement this algorithm in C#" is not a useful problem description. And "Is there a sample implementation for this kind of problem" is a third party resource request, which is off-topic for this site.

Comment: This is an algorithm question.  He has an algorithm in mind but doesn't know it's name.  It's answerable and on topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of the algorithm you are describing is [Exponential Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search), also known as doubling search or galloping search.

The Wikipedia article has a sample implementation that may be of interest.